# How to sort files by part of the filename?

Tags: files, ls, sort, file-management

Given the files below:

```
ABC38388.SC01.StatueGrade_MKP
ABC38388.SC02.Statue_GKP
DEF38389.SC03.Statue_HKP
XYZ38390.SC00.Statue_WKP
```

How can I list them all based on the `SC` value, like this:

```
XYZ38390.SC00.Statue_WKP
ABC38388.SC01.StatueGrade_MKP
ABC38388.SC02.Statue_GKP
DEF38389.SC03.Statue_HKP
```

Answer (score 17):

In this particular case where your file names don't contain any whitespace or other strange characters, you can use `ls` and pipe it through `sort`:

```
$ ls -d -- *.SC* | sort -t. -k2
XYZ38390.SC00.Statue_WKP
ABC38388.SC01.StatueGrade_MKP
ABC38388.SC02.Statue_GKP
DEF38389.SC03.Statue_HKP
```

The `-t` sets the field delimiter and the `-k2` tells `sort` to sort based on the part of the line starting with the 2<sup>nd</sup> field (use `-k2,2` for second field *only*).

For more complex cases, you could print each file name followed by the NULL character (`\0`), then pipe to GNU `sort` using its `-z` option to tell it to read NULL-delimited lines and, finally, use `tr` to change the `\0` back to `\n`:

```
printf '%s\0' *SC* | sort -zt. -k2 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks all... "-k" parameter in sort is confusing for me... on what basis did it pick up the field is confusing me... like k2 for second field ?

Comment: @MRKR the `-t.` tells it to use `.` as the field separator so the `-k2` refers to the second field as defined by `.`.

Comment: @MRKR If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4):

With zsh, you can define your own sorting order for globs with the `oe` or `o+` glob qualifiers:

```
ls -lUd -- *(oe['REPLY=${REPLY#*.SC}'])
```

or:

```
bysc() REPLY=${REPLY#*.SC}
ls -lUd -- *(o+bysc)
```

The sorting function receives the filename in `$REPLY` and is meant to return a string in `$REPLY` that globbing will sort on. Here, we return the part of the file name to the right of the first occurrence of `.SC` (or the full filename if it doesn't contain `.SC`).

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU system and with `zsh` or `bash` as your shell, use this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -z -t. -k3 | \
while IFS="" read -r -d "" f; do
  basename "$f"
done
```

---

- `find` searches for the files in the current directory (`-maxdepth 1`) and prints them null-byte delimited (`-print0`).
- `sort` reads its input null-byte delimited (`-z`) and sorts on the part of the record that starts on the 3rd field (`-k3`) separated by a dot (`-t.`).
- `while` reads the input

  - and `basename` prints its name without path

Answer (score 0):

I would - as I often do - suggest `perl`.

`perl` has a sort function that lets you specify a comparison function. This comparison function is any test that takes two values, and returns `-1`, `0` or `1` depending on relative position.

It iterates the list setting each value as `$a` and `$b` and 'doing the test' for each element.

So by default:

```
$a cmp $b
```

for stringwise comparison, or `sort { $a <=> $b }` for numeric.

But as a result, you can apply arbitrarily complex custom sort criteria:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub sort_by_sc {
   my ( $a_sc ) = $a =~ m/SC(\d+)/;
   my ( $b_sc ) = $b =~ m/SC(\d+)/;
   return $a_sc <=> $b_sc;
}


my @file_list = qw ( 
    ABC38388.SC01.StatueGrade_MKP
    ABC38388.SC02.Statue_GKP
    DEF38389.SC03.Statue_HKP
    XYZ38390.SC00.Statue_WKP
);

print sort sort_by_sc @file_list;
```

Or reduced to a one liner, reading `STDIN` or a file (linefeed delimited, which is usually good enough):

```
perl -e 'print sort {@x = map {/SC(\d+)/}($a,$b); $x[0] <=> $x[1]} <>'
```

You could instead feed it the result of `glob` of a directory pattern instead:

```
perl -e 'print sort {@x = map {/SC(\d+)/}($a,$b); $x[0] <=> $x[1]} glob ( "*SC*")'
```