# Sorting folders in Unix by starting with the second character

Tags: linux, directory, sort

I am trying to sort the listing of directories by starting with the second character.

For example, if I do the code below, the listing of the directories are in order based on the first character.

```
$ ls -1d */
lrodriguez/
mreynolds/
yalberto/
```

What I want to accomplish is to display them as:

```
yalberto/
mreynolds/
lrodriguez/
```

I've looked at the following forum:
[How to sort files by part of the filename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248350/how-to-sort-files-by-part-of-the-filename)
but had no success.

I have tried something like: `ls -1d -- *?[a-z]* | sort -t?[a-z] -k2` but didn't get any results.  Pretty new to the Unix environment and any pointers will be very helpful.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sort`, you can use a key of the form `F.C` to specify a character position *within* a field. So for example

```
$ printf '%s\n' */ | sort -k1.2
yalberto/
mreynolds/
lrodriguez/
```

Note that this will fail if any of the directory names contains a newline.

That could be worked around with GNU `sort` by working with NUL-delimited records instead with:

```
printf '%s\0' */ | sort -zk1.2 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Also note that the expansion of `*/` also includes symlinks to directories.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- *(N/oe['REPLY=${REPLY#?}'])
```

- `print -rC1` prints its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn
- `*(qualifiers)`: glob with glob qualifiers
- `N`: `N`ullglob: expands to nothing if there's no match
- `/`: only select files of type *directory*
- `oe[expression]`: `o`rder the list based on the result of the `e`xpression (of the value of `$REPLY` initially containing the file name after it's been manipulated by the expression)
- `REPLY=${REPLY#?}`: strip the first character off the file name.

You may also want to add the first character at the end like with `REPLY=${REPLY#?}.$REPLY[1]` so  that `asmith`, `bsmith`, `csmith` sort in that order instead of randomly.